# if home css for wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

css conditioning if user is in homepage of wordpress?

I put this

```
<?php if(is_home()) {
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="customHome.css">'
} ?>
```

into my page editor and it did applied the css. but because it's using echo so there will be some bug. it echo out some thing like

```
> echo ' ‘ } ?>
```

in the end of the post.

I want to know where else should I include that? I tried to put in header but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where did you add that code? You should add it in the theme's header file.

Comment: you need a semi-colon after your `echo`

Comment: It looks like you have used `‘` insted of `'` at the end of the echo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append css by using [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) like;

```
function custom_css() {
    if (is_home()) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_style_name', 'path_to_your_css' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_css' );
```

Put above code block to `functions.php`